# Can I store an object constructor into an array or hashtable?

Tags: java, arrays, class, constructor, hashtable

Let's say I have a class `Foo` and another class `Bar` that both extends from a superclass `Foobar`, each one with it's own  constructor.

So, I want to make an application in Java 8 that let's a user choose from a list of objects to implement, and add them to a list —I was thinking of using an array or hashtable—, in this case I want to show a message like:

```
Choose an object of the following list:
 [1] Foo
 [2] Bar
```

The idea is to let the user create multiple instances of such classes and add them to an array. For example, if the user chooses 1, I want to assign a variable with `a[0] = new Foo()`, and then if he chooses 2, `a[1] = new Bar()`, but then, if the user chooses 1 again, then `a[2]` should be a new instance of `Foo`. My first idea was to initialize an array with the constructors like:

```
anArray[1] = new Foo();
anArray[2] = new Bar();
```

The problem with that implementation is that if I call `a[0] = anArray[1]` and then `a[1] = anArray[1]`, then `a[0]`and `a[1]` would be the same object.

What I am looking for is if there is a way of creating an undefined number of instances of each object without having to implement it as a chain of `if else` (because in reality I have more than 2 type of objects). I was thinking of using an array or a hashtable, but I don't know if there is actually a way of doing it.

Comment: What Java version?

Comment: Constructors are provided as `Constructor` by reflection and as such you could store them into some array or collection (then invoke them via `newInstance()`). However you'll probably want to use factory objects instead. Alternatively you could use `anArray[1] = new Foo();` etc. and then create copies by calling `a[0] = anArray[1].clone()` etc.

Comment: @weston I'm using Java 8

Comment: What is the type for anArray?  Is there a common base class?

Comment: @AndrewS Yes, they both extend from a common superclass

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose they implement a common interface (or superclass) `Common`:

```
public interface Common {
}

public class Foo implements Common {
}

public class Bar implements Common {
}
```

Then, in Java 8 we can define an array of [`Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html)s:

```
List<Supplier<Common>> anArray = new ArrayList<>();

anArray.add(Foo::new);
anArray.add(Bar::new);

//or with lambdas:
anArray.add(() -> new Bar());
```

Usage:

```
Common aNewCommon = anArray.get(0).get();
```

Without a `Common` interface (or superclass) you'll have to do some less-than-ideal casting from `Object`.

Comment: Will this work the same way if instead of a common interface the methods have a common superclass?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I store an object constructor into an array or hashtable?

If you are in Java-8+ land then you certainly can.  I'll assume you mean `HashMap` not a `HashTable`.  I would instead create an array of `Factory` objects.  Create a `FooFactory` and a `BarFactory` each which support  create method that returns an object.

```
 public interface MyFactory<T> {
      public T create();
 }

 public class FooFactory implements MyFactory<Foo> {
      public Foo create() {
          return new Foo();
      }
 }

 public class BarFactory implements MyFactory<Bar> {
      public Bar create() {
          return new Bar();
      }
 }
```

Then you can do:

```
MyFactory[] factories = new MyFactory[10];
factories[0] = new FooFactory();
factories[1] = new BarFactory();
...
```

And then you can use the array:

```
Object obj = factories[0].create();
```

Comment: Perhaps explain why you would create all this boilerplate given it's Java 8?

Comment: Heh, your reply got an upvote, but the answer didn't. Go figure.

Comment: Good one @weston!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

A select case statement will be most suitable for this.
The problem here is this, unless they have a known superclass except object, they cannot be put in an array.So assuming that i will proceed.
You can do this using java reflection API.
There, you can load and create instance at runtime.
For the array, make a `Constructor[]`. Study reflection to know what I mean.
This might help you.

Comment: i think an array of type `Object` could hold every object?

Comment: of course, but that as a superclass is too generic for any purpose, unless you know the `class` of the object you want to create by choice given by user. That's why reflection comes in.

Comment: that's why I was supporting select case

Comment: Gratuitous reflection is gratuitous.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [Factory pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)). In java 8 you can do it quite succinctly using lambda expressions.